# "invalid command name" in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I have the following code for listening at a serial port:

```
set timeout -1
log_user 0

set port [lindex $argv 0]

spawn /usr/bin/cu -l $port

proc receive { str } {
  set timeout 5
  expect
  {
    timeout { send_user "\nDone\n"; }
  }
  set timeout -1
}

expect {
  "XXXXXX\r" { receive $expect_out(0,string); exp_continue; }
}
```

Why does this give a

> invalid command name "

error after the 5 second timeout elapses in the procedure? Are the nested expects OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
  expect
  {
    timeout { send_user "\nDone\n"; }
  }
```

Newlines matter in Tcl scripts! When you use `expect` on its own, it just waits for the timeout (and processes any background expecting you've set up; none in this case). The next line, with what you're waiting for, is interpreted as a command all of its own with a very strange name (including newlines, spaces, etc.) which is not at all what you want.

What you actually want to do is this:

```
  expect {
    timeout { send_user "\nDone\n"; }
  }
```

By putting the brace on the same line as the `expect`, you'll get the behaviour that you (presumably) anticipate.